# struts2 send html text back in actionerror or action message

Tags: java, html, struts2

In my web application I want to send some text back in the

```
addActionError("User not logged in. <a href=\"logon\">Click Here</a> to log in");
```

The problem is the html text appears as normal text and does not appear as a link to click on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `escape="false"` attribute on the `<s:actionerror>` tag; it defaults to `true`:

```
<s:actionerror escape="false"/>
```

See the [`<s:actionerror>` docs](http://struts.apache.org/docs/actionerror.html) for more details. Roughly:

```
escape default=false required=false type=Boolean ==> Whether to escape HTML
```